# Cant figure out why the Trigger is invalid?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Following trigger is getting created but on inserting, getting  error "trigger is invalid and failed re-validation"

```
 create or replace trigger check_dept
BEFORE INSERT ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
c number(1);
BEGIN
 select count(*) INTO c from departments where departments.department_id=:new.department_id;

IF c = 0 THEN
insert into departments(department_id,department_name) values (:new.department_id,'others');
END IF;

END;
```

What am i missing ?

Comment: what happens if you compile it manually? Also, are you inserting null in the employee.department_id value?

Comment: No i am not inserting Null values. When i ran this query i didnt see any errors either ALTER TRIGGER check_dept COMPILE;

Comment: is there a missing not null column from departments that you don't insert value in?

Comment: No. The two not null columns are the ones i am inserting in.

Comment: Try executing `SELECT * FROM ALL_ERRORS WHERE NAME='CHECK_DEPT'`.  Are any rows returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the default `HR` schema, the trigger compiles just fine.

```
C:\Users\jcave>sqlplus hr/hr

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Mar 18 16:55:42 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> create or replace trigger check_dept
  2  BEFORE INSERT ON employees
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  DECLARE
  5  c number(1);
  6  BEGIN
  7   select count(*) INTO c from departments where departments.department_id=:new.department_id;
  8
  9  IF c = 0 THEN
 10  insert into departments(department_id,department_name) values (:new.department_id,'others');
 11  END IF;
 12
 13  END;
 14  /

Trigger created.


SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  insert into employees( employee_id, first_name, last_name, email, hire_date, job_id, department_id)
  2*    values( -1, 'Justin', 'Cave', 'foo@bar.com', sysdate, 'AC_ACCOUNT', 10 )
SQL> /

1 row created.
```

If your trigger is invalid, either there is something different about the trigger you posted than the trigger you are actually compiling or you are not using the default `HR` schema in which case you'd need to tell us what your tables look like.

Comment: No this is the exact trigger that i am running and i am using the default hr schema . I have only altered the employee table to make all the colummns except the employee_id and last_name nullable but i dont think that can be an issue with this trigger. I have tried droppping this trigger and again recreating.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to add 'COMMIT' at the end of your code.

Comment: This is a useful answer to this problem. You can't commit in a trigger and DDL (such as `CREATE TRIGGER`) always issues a commit in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a silly thought but do you have access to the view or to the tables that your trigger is accessing? If its a view then perhaps a grant must be added.